# Paho mqtt on internet disconnect not running callback

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have this mqtt class

```
class MQTT():
    def __init__(self):
        # Observer.__init__(self) # DON'T FORGET THIS

        self.mqttClient = paho.Client(client_id=constants.MQTT_CLIENT_ID)
        self.mqttClient.username_pw_set(username=constants.MQTT_BROKER_USERNAME, password=constants.MQTT_BROKER_PASSWORD)

        # assign mqtt event callbacks
        self.mqttClient.on_message = self.on_message
        self.mqttClient.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.mqttClient.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        self.mqttClient.on_socket_close = self.on_disconnect
        self.mqttClient.on_log = self.on_log

   def on_disconnect(self,client, userdata, rc):
        log("MQTT DISCONNECT:",client, userdata, rc)
```

and then

```
mqtt = MQTT()
```

If i run my code it work perfectly but then i have to run some functions when internet connection is lost. So for that i am using `on_disconnect` and after running code if turn of network nothing happen. I want some call back to run on Internet connection lost. Do we have any ?

Comment: You don't appear to ever call `connect()`

Comment: Also nothing will happen straight away, it's going to wait for the keepalive period. How long have you left it?

Comment: @hardillb Yes yes i only added relevant code. So instead of code i added text saying it is working

Comment: The docs suggest you provide a minimum work example, adding one extra line makes the example useful to those that find it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_disconnect` is the right callback for this - the question is when it gets called?

If the network connection is lost your client will only notice it at its next attempt of transmission. So if the client is not about to publish something (or acknowledge a subscription which was received just before the connection dropped) the next transmission will be the `PINGREQ`

By default `keepalive` is set to `60` - that means your client will send a `PINGREQ` every 60 seconds if no other control package was sent within this time interval.

So the `on_disconnect` callback will be called, it just does not happen as fast as you expected. Try a lower `keepalive` to improve on this